# insert data by GET

Tags: php, mysql

I want insert data by GET in my sql but I can not insert data

```
<?php

include("config.php");

$f=$_GET["first_name"];
$l=$_GET["last_name"];
$e=$_GET["email"];
$m=$_GET["mobile"];
$b=$_GET["birthday"];
$g=$_GET["gender"];



$insert="INSERT INTO user ( `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `mobile`, `birthday`, `gender`)
VALUES ('$f', '$l', '$e', '$m', '$b', '$g')";
mysqli_query($insert);



?>
```

I try insert data by this link :

> http://localhost:8888/restfull/insert.php?f=hayoo

Comment: you're using the wrong GET arrays. `?f` ?? that won't work. You also need `&` operators.

Comment: You also didn't pass db connection to the query. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). As for your problem, think about it: you're using values in `$_GET` that don't exist. It's not surprising that doesn't work.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I have used mysqli the code below should most likely run though. As others have mentioned never bind unsanitized data (Even if you think you trust the data it's safe to use prepared statements still).

```
<?php
//Create you db connection 
$conn = new mysqli('server', 'user', 'password', 'databasename');
//Create insert statement. Never concat un-sanitized data in statements 
$insert="INSERT INTO user ( `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `mobile`, `birthday`, `gender`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

//Values corespond to ? except the first param which represents format of expected data. "s" stands for string
$stmt->bind_param(
    'ssssss', 
     $_GET["first_name"], 
     $_GET["last_name"],
     $_GET["email"],
     $_GET["mobile"],
     $_GET["birthday"],
     $_GET["gender"]
);
$stmt->execute();
```

Your url would look like this:
http://localhost:8888/restfull/insert.php?first_name=john&last_name=Doe&email=test@test.com&mobile=0&birthday=May&gender=male

Make sure if you are putting the url above in some type of form you correctly url encode values (I notice many of the values you are collecting will like require it slashes etc).